# Orderby after select clause in C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a VB .Net query which im attempting to convert to C#. I thought i did it correctly but my attempt in C# results in no data returned where as the VB code does return data (both coming from the same data source)

```
Dim MyQuery = From s In MyContext.StudentPlacements _
                    Where (s.StudentLocation.URL = StudentUrl) _
                          Select s _
                         Order By s.Id Descending, MyContext.GenerateRandomId
```

C#

```
IQueryable<StudentPlacement> MyQuery = from s in MyContext.StudentPlacements
                            where (s.StudentLocation.URL == StudentUrl) 
                            orderby s.Id descending, MyContext.GenerateRandomId() 
                            select s;
```

So i searched to see if i could add an orderby after the select in C# but all my attempts didnt seem to work. I dont think you can have an order by after the select in C#? I tried to change my C# code to use a dynamic variable but that didnt do the trick. Used an online converter which gave something different but it didnt compile.

Any idea how i could achieve the same code in C#?

Comment: I suggest you look at the SQL generated in each case.

Comment: Hmm great idea - completely forgot about that. I'll give that a shot

Comment: Are you sure `StudentUrl` is the same in both cases?  I don't see how an order by would change the number of results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VB.Net does case insensitive comparisons for texts so the VB statement

```
s.StudentLocation.URL = StudentUrl
```

Returns different results from the same statement in C#

```
s.StudentLocation.URL == StudentUrl
```

Use

```
s.StudentLocation.URL.ToUpper() == StudentUrl.ToUpper()
```

OR

```
 s.StudentLocation.URL.Equals(StudentUrl,StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

Comment: In this case, it's generating SQL, and Sql Server will do a case-insensitive compare for both languages.